# Can you access an array through a cin input that has the same name as the array?

Tags: c++

```
int a[5]= { 1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5};

char letter;

cin >> letter;
```

If I input a, which is the name of my array, is it possible to retrieve a value from array a by using letter as the array name instead of a. Ex: letter[0] = 1.

Comment: no you can't convert strings to identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported by design.
If you are keen to go ahead, you might consider to use a `std::map`.